# .NET Core - JWT - decrypt token ? (Claims.First returns 'Sequence contains no matching element')

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, token

I send my jwt token as a bearer header so it gets validated

now **I want to decrypt the token** to get the user id to check what's its role and other infos

I thought the best place to do so is the middleware filter

but how to I decrypt the token ?

**tokenS.Claims.First returns 'Sequence contains no matching element'**

```
public async void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
{
    var req = context.HttpContext.Request;

    //---------------------------------------- jwt
    var stream = req.Headers[HeaderNames.Authorization];
    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var bearer = stream[0].Split(" ");
    var jsonToken = tokenHandler.ReadToken(bearer[1]);
    var tokenS = tokenHandler.ReadToken(stream) as JwtSecurityToken;
    var jti = tokenS.Claims.First(claim => claim.Type == ClaimTypes.Name);
```

here is how I encrypt the token when the user authenticates

```
// authentication successful so generate jwt token
var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(settings.JwtSecret);
var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
    {
        Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Id.ToString())
        }),
        Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
        SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
    };
var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
```

thanks for helping me on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I found you don't have any issuer or audience in your jwt token generate method, I suggest you could try to use below JWT generate codes and then it will work well.

Encrypt method:

```
    public static string GetToken2() {

        var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes
        ("YourKey-2374-OFFKDI940NG7:56753253-tyuw-5769-0921-kfirox29zoxv");
        //Generate Token for user 
        var JWToken = new JwtSecurityToken(
            issuer: "http://localhost:45092/",
            audience: "http://localhost:45092/",
            claims: new List<Claim>
{
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Users2222" )
},
            notBefore: new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now).DateTime,
            expires: new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)).DateTime,
            //Using HS256 Algorithm to encrypt Token  
            signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials
            (new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
        );
        string token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(JWToken);
        return token;
    }
```

Middleware:

```
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            // you could get from token or get from session. 
            string token = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
            {
                var tok = token.Replace("Bearer ", "");
                var jwttoken = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().ReadJwtToken(tok);

                 var jti = jwttoken.Claims.First(claim => claim.Type == ClaimTypes.Name);
            }
            await next();

        });
```

Result:

[image]